# Create folder and save PDF

Tags: vba, solidworks

I have a macro that is supposed to do the following;

-Open a Folder Selection Box (where the user selects a folder)

-Open all the drawing files in the selected folder (one by one, one after the other)

-Check to see if there is a folder called "PDF" in the directory, if not then create one

-Save the open drawing file as a pdf, building the save as name from custom properties in the referenced model

-Close the drawing

-Move on to next one

Now my code macro will complete one drawing, close the drawing and show the msgbox if that "PDF" folder exists, if the folder does not exist it will create the folder, save the open drawing, close the drawing and fail on "sFileName = Dir"

If I comment out the "If Dir(PDFpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir PDFpath" and make "pdfpath=currpath" it runs perfectly and saves the drawings all in the selected directory.

How do I create that folder and save the PDFs into it?

```
Option Explicit

Dim swApp           As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel         As SldWorks.ModelDoc
Dim swDraw          As SldWorks.DrawingDoc
Dim swCustProp      As CustomPropertyManager
Dim swView          As SldWorks.View
Dim sFileName       As String
Dim vFileName       As String
Dim Path            As String
Dim nPath           As String
Dim nErrors         As Long
Dim nWarnings       As Long
Dim ConfigName      As String
Dim i               As Long
Dim valOut1         As String
Dim valOut2         As String
Dim resolvedValOut1 As String
Dim resolvedValOut2 As String
Dim PartNo          As String
Dim nFileName       As String
Dim swDocs          As Variant
Dim PDFpath         As String
Dim currpath        As String
Dim PartNoDes       As String

Sub main()
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Path = BrowseFolder("Select a Path/Folder")
    Path = Path + "\"
    sFileName = Dir(Path & "*.slddrw")
    Do Until sFileName = ""
        Set swModel = swApp.OpenDoc6(Path + sFileName, swDocDRAWING, swOpenDocOptions_Silent, "", nErrors, nWarnings)
        Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
        Set swDraw = swApp.ActiveDoc
        Set swView = swDraw.GetFirstView
        Set swView = swView.GetNextView
        Set swModel = swView.ReferencedDocument
        currpath = Left(swDraw.GetPathName, InStrRev(swDraw.GetPathName, "\"))
        PDFpath = currpath & "PDF"
        If Dir(PDFpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir PDFpath

        If swModel.GetType = swDocPART Then
            PartNoDes = Mid(swDraw.GetPathName, InStrRev(swDraw.GetPathName, "\") + 1)
            PartNoDes = Right(PartNoDes, Len(PartNoDes) - 14)
            PartNoDes = Left(PartNoDes, Len(PartNoDes) - 7)
            PartNo = Mid(swModel.GetPathName, InStrRev(swModel.GetPathName, "\") + 1)
            PartNo = Left(PartNo, Len(PartNo) - 7)
            Set swCustProp = swModel.Extension.CustomPropertyManager(swView.ReferencedConfiguration)
            ConfigName = swView.ReferencedConfiguration
            swCustProp.Get2 "Description", valOut1, resolvedValOut1
            swCustProp.Get2 "Revision", valOut2, resolvedValOut2
            nFileName = PDFpath & "\" & PartNo & "-" & ConfigName & "-" & resolvedValOut2 & " " & PartNoDes
            swDraw.SaveAs3 nFileName & ".PDF", 0, 0

        ElseIf swModel.GetType = swDocASSEMBLY Then
            PartNoDes = Mid(swDraw.GetPathName, InStrRev(swDraw.GetPathName, "\") + 1)
            PartNoDes = Right(PartNoDes, Len(PartNoDes) - 11)
            PartNoDes = Left(PartNoDes, Len(PartNoDes) - 7)
            PartNo = Mid(swModel.GetPathName, InStrRev(swModel.GetPathName, "\") + 1)
            PartNo = Left(PartNo, Len(PartNo) - 7)
            Set swCustProp = swModel.Extension.CustomPropertyManager("")
            swCustProp.Get2 "Description", valOut1, resolvedValOut1
            swCustProp.Get2 "Revision", valOut2, resolvedValOut2
            nFileName = PDFpath & "\" & PartNo & "-" & resolvedValOut2 & " " & PartNoDes
            swDraw.SaveAs3 nFileName & ".PDF", 0, 0

        End If
        swApp.QuitDoc swDraw.GetPathName
        Set swDraw = Nothing
        Set swModel = Nothing
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop
MsgBox "All Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: I would use `FileSystemObject` instead of `Dir` since you are dealing with 2 different folders.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using  filesystemobject.

See code below;

```
Option Explicit

Dim swApp           As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel         As SldWorks.ModelDoc
Dim swDraw          As SldWorks.DrawingDoc
Dim swCustProp      As CustomPropertyManager
Dim swView          As SldWorks.View
Dim sFileName       As String
Dim Path            As String
Dim nPath           As String
Dim nErrors         As Long
Dim nWarnings       As Long
Dim ConfigName      As String
Dim i               As Long
Dim valOut1         As String
Dim valOut2         As String
Dim resolvedValOut1 As String
Dim resolvedValOut2 As String
Dim PartNo          As String
Dim nFileName       As String
Dim swDocs          As Variant
Dim PDFpath         As String
Dim PartNoDes       As String
Dim FSO             As Object
Dim FolderPath      As String
Dim strquotes(110)  As String
Dim lngIndex        As Long

Sub main()
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Path = BrowseFolder("Select a Path/Folder")
    Path = Path + "\"
    PDFpath = Path & "PDF"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    FolderPath = PDFpath
    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(FolderPath) = False Then
        MkDir (PDFpath)
    Else
        'MsgBox "Folder exist"
    End If

    sFileName = Dir(Path & "*.slddrw")
    Do Until sFileName = ""

        Set swModel = swApp.OpenDoc6(Path + sFileName, swDocDRAWING, swOpenDocOptions_Silent, "", nErrors, nWarnings)
        Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
        Set swDraw = swApp.ActiveDoc
        Set swView = swDraw.GetFirstView
        Set swView = swView.GetNextView
        Set swModel = swView.ReferencedDocument

        If swModel.GetType = swDocPART Then
            PartNoDes = Mid(swDraw.GetPathName, InStrRev(swDraw.GetPathName, "\") + 1)
            PartNoDes = Right(PartNoDes, Len(PartNoDes) - 14)
            PartNoDes = Left(PartNoDes, Len(PartNoDes) - 7)
            PartNo = Mid(swModel.GetPathName, InStrRev(swModel.GetPathName, "\") + 1)
            PartNo = Left(PartNo, Len(PartNo) - 7)
            Set swCustProp = swModel.Extension.CustomPropertyManager(swView.ReferencedConfiguration)
            ConfigName = swView.ReferencedConfiguration
            swCustProp.Get2 "Description", valOut1, resolvedValOut1
            swCustProp.Get2 "Revision", valOut2, resolvedValOut2
            nFileName = PDFpath & "\" & PartNo & "-" & ConfigName & "-" & resolvedValOut2 & " " & PartNoDes
            swDraw.SaveAs3 nFileName & ".PDF", 0, 0

        ElseIf swModel.GetType = swDocASSEMBLY Then
            PartNoDes = Mid(swDraw.GetPathName, InStrRev(swDraw.GetPathName, "\") + 1)
            PartNoDes = Right(PartNoDes, Len(PartNoDes) - 11)
            PartNoDes = Left(PartNoDes, Len(PartNoDes) - 7)
            PartNo = Mid(swModel.GetPathName, InStrRev(swModel.GetPathName, "\") + 1)
            PartNo = Left(PartNo, Len(PartNo) - 7)
            Set swCustProp = swModel.Extension.CustomPropertyManager("")
            swCustProp.Get2 "Description", valOut1, resolvedValOut1
            swCustProp.Get2 "Revision", valOut2, resolvedValOut2
            nFileName = PDFpath & "\" & PartNo & "-" & resolvedValOut2 & " " & PartNoDes
            swDraw.SaveAs3 nFileName & ".PDF", 0, 0

        End If
        swApp.QuitDoc swDraw.GetPathName
        Set swDraw = Nothing
        Set swModel = Nothing
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop
MsgBox ("All drawings in " & Path & " saved as PDF!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Lormanism of the day :" & vbNewLine & strquotes(lngIndex))

End Sub
```